# Copy text with all the font properties and paste it anywhere

Tags: android, textview, copy-paste

I want to copy text with the same font style, same font color from TextView in Android application and paste it anywhere(like message app, WhatsApp etc.) with all the TextView font properties (style, color, size etc.).

I use a .ttf file for different font style.

How to copy that text with all the properties?

Comment: So where you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

The copy-paste option is a system operation, and even if you'd find a way to change it to get in all the font properties, it still depends on the receiving applications to implement your custom paste and also to have the same .tff files for the custom fonts, etc..